# Come si è passato dal pianeta Giove al manifestarsi allegro?

Tags: word-meaning, etymology, adjectives

Nell'italiano moderno, il significato più comune dell'aggettivo [*gioviale*](https://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/gioviale/) è il seguente, tratto dal vocabolario Treccani:

> **2.** Più com., con riferimento a persona, abitualmente allegro, lieto, sereno, disposto a cogliere il lato più piacevole delle cose e a diffondere esternamente l’interna allegria: *un uomo g.; carattere, indole, temperamento, umore g*.; per estens., riferito alle manifestazioni esteriori: *aspetto, faccia g.; modi gioviali*.

Ora, secondo il [*Grande dizionario della lingua italiana*](http://www.gdli.it/JPG/GDLI06/00000841.jpg), tale senso di *gioviale* è derivato dall'accezione come aggettivo per qualificare qualcosa che ha a che vedere col pianeta Giove, a cui si attribuiva un influsso benefico sugli esseri viventi.

Attira la mia attenzione il fatto che la prima attestazione scritta di questa accezione del termine riportata da questo dizionario  sia una frase tratta dalla [*Ragion di stato*](https://books.google.es/books?id=TJAnBwuPq78C&pg=PA93&lpg=PA93&dq=%22I+Francesi,+che+sono+di+natura+allegra+e+gioviale%22++.%22non+fanno+conto+nessuno+delle+lettere%22&source=bl&ots=3Gi-IS2a7w&sig=ACfU3U0RTajabgVmFdQPnX9POoC4oR9vXg&hl=it&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjEgqOcl-fwAhUmMewKHbmeAM4Q6AEwAHoECAQQAQ#v=onepage&q=%22I%20Francesi%2C%20che%20sono%20di%20natura%20allegra%20e%20gioviale%22%20%20.%22non%20fanno%20conto%20nessuno%20delle%20lettere%22&f=false) di Giovanni Botero, della [fine del secolo XVI](https://it.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Della_Ragion_di_Stato):

> Per lo secondo effetto i Francesi, che sono di natura allegra e gioviale (parlo de' nobili), non fanno conto nessuno delle lettere né de' litterati, e Ludovico XI Re di Francia, [...].

Cioè, questo significato di "gioviale" è entrato relativamente tardi nella lingua in comparazione a, per esempio, ["marziale"](http://www.gdli.it/JPG/GDLI09/00000864.jpg) nel senso di qualcosa di carattere guerriero o militare, che si trova già nel Trecento.

Curiosamente, però, l'aggettivo "jovial", con pronunce diverse, con lo stesso significato di "gioviale", si usa in parecchie lingue romanze: castigliano, catalano, francese e portoghese. Questo è per dire che, se, come pare, questa accezione di "gioviale" deriva della convinzione che il pianeta Giove avesse qualche influsso sugli esseri viventi, tale credenza dovrebbe essere abbastanza diffusa.

Qualcuno di voi saprebbe aggiungere più dettagli su questa derivazione? Quali caratteristiche associate a Giove erano correlate con le manifestazioni di allegria delle persone?

Comment: Suppongo che venga dall'interpretazione astrologica del pianeta. Per quello che vale… https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Giove_(astrologia)

Comment: Mmmm, @egreg: dalla lettura del *Paradiso* conoscevo la relazione con la giustizia, ma non sapevo che avesse a che vedere con la buona sorte.

Comment: Forse, come dice Beatrice a Dante («Muta pensier; pensa ch’i’ sono // presso a colui ch’ogne torto disgrava») il fatto che si faccia giustizia ci dovrebbe far esser lieti?

Comment: La Commedia non è l'unica fonte.

Comment: Certamente, @egreg: è questa la ragione per cui ho posto la domanda.

Comment: "_Quali caratteristiche associate a Giove erano correlate con le manifestazioni di allegria delle persone?_". Immagino che Giove sia associato alla prosperità ed alla buona sorte perché Giove era il padre di tutti gli dei, quindi essere sotto la sua protezione significava avere successo assicurato in qualsiasi impresa. Va da sé che una persona a cui va sempre tutto bene sia una persona tendenzialmente allegra, di buon umore

Comment: Va bene, @secan: ho aggiunto qualche dettaglio alla domanda.